# onSaveInstanceState saving state of ImageButton

Tags: android, save

I am using an ImageButton to select Profile Photo of the user in my sign up process. To handle the rotation between portrait and landscape mode. i want to save the state of the background.

For the EditText i am doing this

onSaveInstanceState

```
EditText FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
String firstName = FirstName.getText().toString();
savedInstanceState.putString("FirstName", firstName);
```

onRestoreInstanceState

```
    String firstName = savedInstanceState.getString("FirstName");
    if (firstName != null) {
        EditText FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
        FirstName.setText(firstName);
    }
```

How can i do the same for the ImageButton ?

i am setting the ImageButton like this

```
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // MEDIA GALLERY
            selectedImagePath = getPhotoPath(selectedImageUri);

            // OI FILE Manager
            filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            // NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                SelectedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                DisplayPhoto.setImageBitmap(SelectedPhoto);
                String bans = DisplayPhoto.getBackground().toString();
                Log.i("Bakasura", bans);
            } else{
                SelectedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filemanagerstring);
                DisplayPhoto.setImageBitmap(SelectedPhoto);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're saving the state specifically to deal with rotation, your best option here is to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`; included for just such a purpose. Override this method in the Activity to return the image itself (or an object which contains it):

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
{
   return bitmapImage;
}
```

Then be prepared to receive it again in `onCreate`:

```
Object last = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
if( last != null )
{
   DisplayPhoto.setImageBitmap( (Bitmap) last );
}
```

Note that in Honeycomb and later, you should use the `setRetainInstance()` on a fragment, rather than use this method; but until compatibility no earlier than Honeycomb is acceptable, this is the best solution.

Comment: Certainly!  It works in Honeycomb as well; but the API has a note about it being deprecated, which means it may be discontinued as soon as Ice Cream Sandwich (though I doubt it'll die that quickly)

Answer (score 1):

you can save `uri` of the image.
and use

```
imagebutton.setImageURI(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant check *String* with `=`
ie.

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String selectedImagePath ="";
selectedImagePath = getPhotoPath(selectedImageUri);

          if (!selectedImagePath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                SelectedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                DisplayPhoto.setImageBitmap(SelectedPhoto);
                String bans = DisplayPhoto.getBackground().toString();
                Log.i("Bakasura", bans);
            } else{
                SelectedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filemanagerstring);
                DisplayPhoto.setImageBitmap(SelectedPhoto);
            }
```

Comment: Jazz, this isn't correct.  String is an object like any other and a comparison with `null` is not the same as checking for an empty string.

Additionally, if `selectedImagePath == null` is `true`, your code above would fail with a `NullPointerException`; Harsha's would not.